# Multiple notes at once in sound

Tags: sound

I am trying to write a sound such that I can play double or triple stops in a Sound style. 
I am trying to do

```
eantieinteraction =  
  Sound[{Ds[3], Cn[3], {Ds[6] + En[6], Fn[4]}, Cn[3], Dn[3]}, 10]
```

where `A[n]` is a `SoundNote` with duration `n` and pitch A. When I evaluate the above code, I get this output

> ```
> Sound[
>  {SoundNote[DSharp, 3, Violin], 
>   SoundNote[C, 3, Violin], 
>   SoundNote[DSharp, 6, Violin] + SoundNote[E, 5, Violin] + SoundNote[F, 4, Violin], 
>   SoundNote[C, 3, Violin], 
>   SoundNote[D, 3, Violin]},
>  10]
> ```

Is it possible to do double stops in this way?

Comment: I did figure out a kind of hacky way of doing it using an EmitSound

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SoundNote.html . `SoundNote` has time intervals specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note much of a musician, so I'm not sure if the following code produces what you want, but I hope it does.

```
Cn[tmin_, tmax_] := {"C", {tmin, tmax}}
Dn[tmin_, tmax_] := {"D", {tmin, tmax}}
Ds[tmin_, tmax_] := {"D#", {tmin, tmax}}
En[tmin_, tmax_] := {"E", {tmin, tmax}}
Fn[tmin_, tmax_] := {"F", {tmin, tmax}}

notes = {Ds[0, 3], Cn[3, 6], Ds[6, 12], En[6, 11], Fn[6, 10], Cn[12, 15], Dn[15, 18]};

Sound[{"Violin"}~Join~(SoundNote @@@ notes)]
```

[image: sound]

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the job